# Dynamic Combo box ItemListener

Tags: combobox, itemlistener

I am trying to load 5 combo boxes dynamically by parsing an xml file. Based on the option selected in the first combo box i would like to change the values of other four combo boxes. Can you please suggest few examples for this.

I have browsed and found few. However, did not help me much.

code snippet is below. To parse the xml and load to combo box

```
        File fXmlFile = new File("c:\\DataXML.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList DeviceList = (NodeList) doc.getElementsByTagName("PICDevice");
        int totaldevices = DeviceList.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total no of devices : " + totaldevices);
        for(int s=0; s<DeviceList.getLength() ; s++){
            Node firstDeviceNode1 = DeviceList.item(s);
            Element firstDeviceElement1 = (Element)firstDeviceNode1;
            System.out.println("Device Name : " +
                    firstDeviceElement1.getAttribute("Description"));
            NodeList firstCLCList1 = firstDeviceElement1.getElementsByTagName("CLCNum");
            int totalCLCs1 = firstCLCList1.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of CLCs : " + totalCLCs1);
            for(int i=0; i<totalCLCs1 ; i++){
                Element firstCLCElement = (Element)firstCLCList1.item(i);
                System.out.println("CLC Name : " +
                firstCLCElement.getAttribute("Description"));
                String value = firstCLCElement.getAttribute("Description");
                CLCcombo.addItem(value);
                ArrayList<String> CLCelements = new ArrayList<String>();
                //List<String> CLCelements = new ArrayList<String>();
                boolean add = CLCelements.add(value);
          //      String[] CLCelements = firstCLCElement.getAttribute("Description");

            }
            }
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("CLCNum");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            Node node = nList.item(0);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                String Mux1elements = (getTagValue("Mux1Inputs", eElement));
                String Mux2elements = (getTagValue("Mux2Inputs", eElement));
                String Mux3elements = (getTagValue("Mux3Inputs", eElement));
                String Mux4elements = (getTagValue("Mux4Inputs", eElement));
                String delims = "[,]+";
                String[] Mux1tokens  = Mux1elements.split(delims);
                String[] Mux2tokens  = Mux2elements.split(delims);
                String[] Mux3tokens  = Mux3elements.split(delims);
                String[] Mux4tokens  = Mux4elements.split(delims);

                for (int i = 0; i < Mux1tokens.length; i++){
                    mux1combo.addItem(Mux1tokens[i]);
                    String[] mux1elements = Mux1tokens;
            //        mux1combo = mux1elements;
                    }
                for (int i = 0; i < Mux2tokens.length; i++){
                    mux2combo.addItem(Mux2tokens[i]);
                    }
                for (int i = 0; i < Mux3tokens.length; i++){
                    mux3combo.addItem(Mux3tokens[i]);
                    }
                for (int i = 0; i < Mux4tokens.length; i++){
                    mux4combo.addItem(Mux4tokens[i]);
                    }
                panel.add(mux1combo, BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel.add(mux2combo, BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel.add(mux3combo, BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel.add(mux4combo, BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel.add(CLCcombo, BorderLayout.WEST);
                mux1combo.setEditable(true);
                mux2combo.setEditable(true);
                mux3combo.setEditable(true);
                mux4combo.setEditable(true);
                CLCcombo.setEditable(true);
        //        CLCcombo.addItemListener(new Sample_xml());

                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                jlbLabel1 = new JLabel("Multiplexer1");
                panel.add(jlbLabel1);
       }
    }
```

I donno how to write item listner for this. Can you please help me.
I am sorry this might very simple question. I am beginner with no sufficient time to learn.

Thanks for any help!!!